# If...ELSE with subquery in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, subquery

in the table 'chat':

[image]

I would like to delete messages if they have been deleted by *both* sender an recipient. If, however, a user is the first to delete a message, this should just be recorded under "deleted_by" with his user id (until the second user also deletes the message).

For message #3 and user #1 my query would look like so:

```
IF
    (SELECT deleted_by from chat WHERE id=3) <> '1' AND (SELECT deleted_by from chat WHERE id=3) <> '0' THEN
    DELETE FROM chat WHERE id=3
ELSE 
    UPDATE chat
    SET deleted_by=1
    WHERE id=3
END IF
```

This should delete message #3, but instead I get an error. Can you help me make my according [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c0714a/5) work?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A subquery isn't needed. Instead, you can just delete the row if the other user has already marked it deleted and if it still exists, mark it deleted:

```
DELETE FROM chat WHERE id = 3 AND deleted_by <> 0;
UPDATE chat SET deleted_by = 4 WHERE id = 3;
```

Comment: Right, thank you! Just for curiosity, though: how could the same result be achived with if...else?

Comment: I think you'd have to use a compound statement for that. I haven't done anything with MySQL for a while, so I can't come up with a working example right now. Anyway, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-compound-statements.html